# PostgreSQL xpath - by date condition

Tags: xml, postgresql, xpath

I have xml stored in postgres db

```
<data>
    <contract>
        <details>
            <code>BAC</code>
            <type>SU</type>
            <amount>879</amount>
        </details>
        <start_date>15062020</start_date>
    </contract>
    <contract>
        <details>
            <code>BAC</code>
            <type>SU</type>
            <amount>879</amount>
        </details>
        <start_date>15062019</start_date>
    </contract>
</data>
```

What I need is to filter contracts where code is equal to BAC and type to SU (yeah, both contracts are equal to this condition). But I also need to filter start date, where start_date is less than current date so first contract should be filtered. For some reason it isn't.

Here is my code:

```
select
 id,

  unnest(
    xpath(
      'sum(/data/details[code=="BAC" and type="SU"] and start_date >='
        || to_char(current_date, 'DDMMYYYY') 
        || ']/amount/text())', 
      xmlparse(document xml)
    )
  )::text::numeric as current_contracts


from my_db
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using PG 10+, you can use XMLTABLE and after that manipulate the result like a table, is more easy

```
with sub as (
SELECT tabla_xml.*

FROM (VALUES 
 ('<data>
    <contract>
        <details>
            <code>BAC</code>
            <type>SU</type>
            <amount>879</amount>
        </details>
        <start_date>15062020</start_date>
    </contract>
    <contract>
        <details>
            <code>BAC</code>
            <type>SU</type>
            <amount>879</amount>
        </details>
        <start_date>15062019</start_date>
    </contract>
</data>'::xml) )  AS t (data),
XMLTABLE ('//data/contract/details'
PASSING t.data
COLUMNS code text PATH 'code',
type text PATH 'type',
amount real PATH 'amount',
 start_date text path '../start_date' ) tabla_xml)

 select * from sub where code='BAC' and type='SU'
```

you will get:

```
BAC SU  879 15062020
BAC SU  879 15062019
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your *XPath* is off. Please try the following as a starting point.

> XPath

```
/data/contract/details[code="BAC" and type="SU"]/amount/text()
```

> XPath with date

/data/contract[start_date ge "15062020"]/details[code="BAC" and type="SU"]/amount/text()

Comment: yeah, but what about that filtering date? Only second contract should be counted

Comment: I don't have Postresql. That's why I explicitly said "a starting point". I showed you a proper XPath. The remaining part to substitute a hard-coded value to current date.